# "one main use of X" vs. "one of the main uses of X"

Tags: difference

I wrote:

> **One of the main uses of** the post-assignments is to set some global variables.

Can I reduce it to:

> **One main use of** the post-assignments is to set some global variables.

Are they equivalent? If yes, what is the trick or related grammar here? I mean how "uses" is changed to "use"...

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Not only would I agree to the reduction, I'd highly recommend it. And to me, it's not a grammar issue, more a style issue, that is, trying to be concise in writing.

Comment: No difference in meaning, except that the latter (one of......) is more common.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+main+use%2C+one+of+the+main+uses&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20main%20use%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20the%20main%20uses%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> what is the trick or related grammar here? I mean how "uses" is
>   changed to "use"...

One of the important thing**s**... A member of the set of specific Important Things....

One important thing...  no **set** is involved; we have one thing, which is important

So:

One of the main use**s**  ...  a member of the set Primary Uses

Plural noun, **uses**.

P.S. Others may disagree, but "one main use" is ungrammatical, IMO.  There is only one main use, so it would be "*the* main use". You could argue that "main" has been watered down to mean "important", and so **one** is licensed:

> You should hold your sit-in in one main building on campus.

Don't try to occupy *several* important buildings.

> You should hold your sit-in in one of the main buildings on campus.

Choose one of the important "high-visibility" buildings.

Comment: I agree about "one main use". The primary or main use is not one of many. If someone wants to say "One important use", then they should say that. It seemed awkward to me when I read it.

Comment: @ColleenV you mean "one important use of X is Y" conveys that X has several uses and one of them which is important is Y? but it's not conveyed by "one main use of X"? because in my intention, X can have other uses too.

Comment: It comes down, Ahmad, to the understanding of "main".  According to one understanding of "main", it means "the primary" or "chief" not merely "important".

Comment: @Ahmad I think that you would be understood if you wrote "one main use", but it would be better to use 'one important use' if you mean there are several important uses, or use "the primary use" or "the main use' if you mean there is one use that matters more than all the others.